# What is the difference between X-ray photoelectron spectroscopy and X-ray absorption spectroscopy?

Tags: spectroscopy

XPS is used for surface chemical state identification. 
But other than that, is XAS just an inverse of XPS?

Answer (score 1):

You could easily google this...

*[X-ray photoelectron spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_photoelectron_spectroscopy)* uses low energy monochromatic x-rays to excite electrons from atoms near the surface of a sample. The kinetic energy of the electrons is then measured and then the binding energy of the electrons can be calculated.

*[X-ray absorption spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_absorption_spectroscopy)* measure the attenuation of a x-ray beam as a function of x-ray wavelength (or energy). So what you are detecting is the absorption edges of the atoms in the sample.

Comment: @porphyrin - Yes. Thank you for the need for a correction.

Comment: But from the absorption edge, can we also calculate the binding energy?

Comment: For inner electrons you can look binding energies in a table. You really don't need to measure them again.